# Does PHP 7 handle requests asynchronously by default?

Tags: php, asynchronous, nonblocking

I have been writing PHP for the last 3.5 years and I love it. When the recent **PHP v/s Nodejs** buzz came around, the one thing that always got the limelight was the fact that **Nodejs** implemented non-blocking (or asynchronous) I/O by default and PHP did not.

However, when I recently tried implementing a simple asynchronous request router in PHP (using the *exec()* function) and tried contrasting my code with a standard (supposedly synchronous request handler script), I noticed something strange.

Before moving further on the explanation, I would like you to take a look at the code below.

**sync.php**: *the one that's supposed to put all further requests on hold until the current one is done processing*:

```
<?php
    $a = $argv[1];
    echo "starting: ".$a;
    $ar = array();
    $sum = 0;
    $ul = 15000;
    for($i = 1; $i < $ul; $i++){
        $ar[$i] = $i;
    }
    for($i = 1; $i < $ul;  $i++){
        for($j = 1; $j < $ul; $j++){
            $sum += $ar[$j];
        }
    }
    echo "\n\nDone: ".$a."\nResult: ".$sum."\n";
?>
```

I did two kinds of tests.

First, I ran four instances of the terminal on my computer and executed:

```
php sync.php 1
```

in all of them **at the same time**.

Next, I turned on my XAMPP server, exposed my localhost via [serveo](https://serveo.net) and made three requests from three different devices to this script at the same time.

THE RESULTS WERE UNEXPECTED.

No matter how many requests I send, all of them (seem to) get executed in parallel and the result is displayed on all the terminal windows/browser tabs (almost) at the same time (considering the 1-2 second delay incurred while manually running the commands in each terminal window).

This is not in accordance with the fact that PHP implements blocking I/O (that's what occurs to me). What I expected instead is to get a total burst time of

```
n * 4 seconds
```

where n is the time taken to process each request (approximately 8 seconds on my laptop).

So, **why do the requests get processed asynchronously**?? Is it because the **for loop** is one of the functions that get executed asynchronously or does it not have anything to do with the blocking I/O model at all??

Comment: A single PHP *process* is blocking. That's why webservers run multiple in a FPM pool or a bunch of Apache workers. You've done essentially the same thing - you ran four separate PHP processes in four separate terminal windows.

Comment: Yes, servers in PHP are multi-process (while a downside of NodeJs is it is single-process, maybe a reason why they HAD to implement asyncronous)

Comment: @ceejayoz Then what about the requests sent from three different devices via browsers?

Comment: @progyammer If the server has three available PHP workers, all three requests will be executed simultaneously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have misunderstood what is being discussed regarding blocking I/O.

Each time you run a PHP script from the command-line, it executes in a completely separate process, which doesn't know about any other PHP script running on the machine. You can execute it multiple times for exactly the same reason you can run a web browser and a text editor at the same time - the OS is scheduling the processes on one or more processor cores.

In the web server example, it's slightly more complex, but the same principle applies: each request you make to the web server creates either a new process, or a new thread within the process, and the PHP script runs inside that.

What people are discussing regarding blocking I/O is something completely different: when you access something external *within* your PHP code, such as fetching web content with an HTTP request. Imagine this loop, using an imaginary HTTP library:

```
foreach ( $urls as $url ) {
    $results[] =  $httpClient->fetchUrl($url);
}
```

If written using the built-in PHP functionality, this will *stop running and wait for the remote server to respond* each time around the loop. So for 10 requests each taking a second, it will take 10 seconds to complete the loop.

"Non-blocking I/O" means implementing functions like `fetchUrl` so that they *return immediately*, even though the HTTP response hasn't come back. That way, you can run lots of HTTP requests at once: in the example loop, you would get all 10 responses back after 1 second. You'd then have some way to get the results, such as a "promise".

It's possible to implement this in PHP, but there are no native functions which do it by default and in a user-friendly way.

More complex still, a system can implement this for *input*: whenever you're waiting for something external, you can check if a new web request has come in, and start processing that. This can effectively mimic multiple threads, which is how NodeJS is able to handle a large amount of traffic with a thread per request.

Answer (score 2):

A single PHP *process* is blocking. You can, for example, use the [built-in development server](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php), which will start a single-process webserver. Per the note there:

> The web server runs only one single-threaded process, so PHP applications will stall if a request is blocked.

As this is problematic for obvious reasons if you have thousands of people hitting your website at once, there's an easy solution - **multiple PHP processes**. This can be set up in a variety of ways - Apache will [fire up multiple webserver workers](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/worker.html), or you can run [PHP-FPM ("FastCGI Process Manager"](http://php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.php)).

As long as their are free workers sitting around, they will process incoming requests in parallel.

Comment: So, basically, once a request has been put to processing, the request "router" is available to deal with further requests - something that Nodejs was made to behave like since Js is originally single threaded - right??

Comment: @progyammer There's a parent process that doles requests out to the various workers. The fundamental result is the same - ability to handle multiple requests at once.

Comment: You can use ReactPHP (https://reactphp.org/) or AMP (https://amphp.org/) for running parallel (HTTP) requests on a single threaded webserver. They use PHP promises similar to nodeJS/javascript. As for low-level you might also use sockets (http://php.net/manual/en/sockets.examples.php).